# Class Library Package for Onion Architecture - version issues

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to create an Onion Architecture project for ASP.NET Core. I am running into some issues with Referencing class libraries and other errors that show up only during Build. From the image below, the first issue seems to be the DataAnnotations, I added System.ComponentModel.Annotations (didn't find the old version System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) but the error says that I don't have the 4.5.1 version, I did install the 5.4 version...do I need both?
The second question is related to LINQ queries, complaining about missing System.Runtime.

[image: .NET Class Library Package]

My project.json in LifeLine.Core is as follows:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "LifeLine.Core Class Library",
  "authors": [ "212040799" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
  }
}
```

And my project.json in LifeLine.Infrastructure is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "LifeLine.Infrastructure Class Library",
  "authors": [ "212040799" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "LifeLine.Core": "1.0.0-*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your project.json

Comment: added the project.json for each of the projects in the original thread above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is a 'Class Library Package' project, seems though I had to add Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc to it.